# How to find the major and minor axes of a convex hull?

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a set of particles in a gravitationally bound system. The shape of the particles change with time, I have used a convex hull algorithm to "enclose" the particles of the cloud. I want to find the major and the minor axes of the cloud.

```
hulls = [hull1, hull2, hull3, hull4, hull5]

for hull in hulls:
    for simplex in hull.simplices:
        plt.plot(hull.points[simplex, 0], hull.points[simplex, 1], '-', color='black')
    
    points = hull.points[hull.vertices] # shape: (#vertices, #coordinates)
    max_distance = 0
    major_axis = None
    for i in range(len(points)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(points)):
            distance = np.linalg.norm(points[i] - points[j])
            if distance > max_distance:
                max_distance = distance
                major_axis = (points[i], points[j])

    plt.plot([major_axis[0][0], major_axis[1][0]], [major_axis[0][1], major_axis[1][1]], color='black')
```

[image]

The plot shows the cloud changing with time. Each cloud is for a different time.

I have been able to get the major axes from this. But not the minor axes. How can I do it? Basically just need the distance of the perpendicular through the middle of the major axis. This is a aspect ratio problem. I need the length and width of the cloud. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: PCA will give a good approximation in linear time.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/d62/tutorial_bounding_rotated_ellipses.html